# React Native - Delete item from array with Key

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have an array of image uri's which are presented in the UI as follows:

[image]

```
{this.state.ADImageArray.map((prop, key) => {

   return (
     <View style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnailBlock}>
      <Image
        source={{uri: prop, isStatic: true}}
        style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnail}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removephoto} style={PhotoStyles.removePhotoLnk}>
          <Image
            source={require('../images/icons/ico-removeImg.png')}
            style={PhotoStyles.removePhotoImg}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   );
})}
```

I want an image to be removed from the array whenever the orange delete button is clicked.

I have the this.removephoto action ready - but wonder how can i remove a particular image in this context - is it possible to remove the image by key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible for you to remove the item using it index. So your removephoto function can be of the form

```
removephoto = (index) => {
   let result = this.state.ADImageArray.filter((item, key) => key != index)
   this.setState({ADImageArray: result})
}
```

then you call it as follows

```
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removephoto(key)} style={PhotoStyles.removePhotoLnk}>
```

Or alternatively you can remove the link by its url you just need to change the implimentation of the removephoto() function to the one below

```
removephoto = (url) => {
   let result = this.state.ADImageArray.filter((item, key) => item != url)
   this.setState({ADImageArray: result})
}
```

and then you call it as follows

```
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removephoto(prop)} style={PhotoStyles.removePhotoLnk}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `key` to your click handler like so

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removephoto(key)}>
```

Be aware that this will create a new function each time, so for performance reasons it's better to bind the handler, like so:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removephoto.bind(this, key)}>
```

Then your handler looks something like

```
removephoto = (key) => {
  const { ADImageArray } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    ADImageArray: ADImageArray.filter((item, i) => i !== key)
  });
}
```

Check out this working [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/Byw6zDYwS)